# 'ReverseManyToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'all'

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django and I'm trying to access products that belong to category through `Category` model. I'm using a foreign key in `Product` for categories.
These are my models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("shop:category", kwargs= 
                {"category_slug": self.slug})

class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, 
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, 
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    description = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=image_name)
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    avaliable = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
         return reverse("shop:product", kwargs={
                       "product_slug": self.slug,                                           
                       "product_ctgr_slug": 
                                   self.category.slug,})
```

My Views:

```
class CategoryDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Category
    category_products = Category.product_set.all()
    slug_url_kwarg = "category_slug"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['categories'] = self.categories
        context['category_products'] = self.category_products
        return context
```

But Django gives me an `AttributeError: 'ReverseManyToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'all'`.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For a model, the reverse relation, is just a *descriptor*, only for a `some_category`, the `some_category.product_set` will work. You will need to query in reverse.

Comment: How do I chose specific category from inside view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `product_set` as related name created by default in Django, or you can better create a related name yourself. A *product* belongs to a *category*, but a *category* can have many *products*. Follow this principle and make your queries human readable.

For this purpose set the related name for `category` in the class `Product`:

```
category = models.ForeignKey(
    Category,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    related_name='products'
)
```

Now in your `views.py` you have to make some changes.

```
class CategoryDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Category
    # remove the line below
    category_products = Category.product_set.all()
    # don't prefix the fields like this, it's ugly and redundant
    # call it just slug, not category_slug, adjust in urls.py
    slug_url_kwarg = "category_slug"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # where did you get self.categories?
        context['categories'] = self.categories
        # and this won't work anymore too
        context['category_products'] = self.category_products
        return context
```

In the `CategoryDetailView` you're going to display just one Category. It is detailed view - it implies just a single object. Therefore you're not using something like *categories*. The object is available in the method. This is how we rewrite it:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    products = self.object.products.all()
    context['products'] = products
    return context
```

Answer (score 5):

The real problem is that the original poster tried to call the RelatedManager.all() function from the *class* instead of from an *instance*.

`category_products = Category.product_set.all()`

*Category* is the class name. Since it is the class, it does does not and cannot know about the related products of a *single* instance.

You have to call the RelatedManagers.all() function from an instance, not the class itself.

Answer (score 2):

This may help:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    instance = self.get_object()
    context['categories'] = self.categories
    context['category_products'] = instance.product_set.all()
    return context
```

Comment: It helped. Thank you!

Comment: As I wrote in my answer, name your variables meaningful. It is `DetailView` for a category, not categories. The products belong to this category, no need to prefix it like `category_products`, `products` is better (simple is better than complex).