# django reverse relation query from ForeignKey

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, relational-database

Let's say I have a couple of simple models defined:

```
class Pizza(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    # Get the name of topping here
    ...

class Topping(models.Model):
    pizza = models.ForeignKey(Pizza)
```

One thing I can do is a query on `Topping`, but and access that `Pizza`. But that is not what I want. I want to do a reverse-relation query. I want to get the `Topping` inside `Pizza`, if such `Topping` exists, There may and will be some `Pizza` without `Topping`. Using `django` and `drf`

How can I achieve this?

I even tried:

```
Pizza.objects.filter()
.prefetch_related("topping_set")
```

*we don't like pineapple pizza*

Comment: If you are going to add only one topping to pizza, you can make use of foreignkey field else if pizza can have multiple toppings, then you have to use manytomany field. Create Topping model with details about each toppings. Create a Pizza model with manytomany field. Hence each pizza can have multiple toppings and you can get the list of toppings instance used in pizza and also  you can get list of pizzas that using any specific toppings. Refer below link for understanding manytomany field. 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['ReverseManyToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'all'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51950416/reversemanytoonedescriptor-object-has-no-attribute-all)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do. Do you want to get the toppings coming from certain pizzas, or to filter pizzas against their toppings? Can you give us a more concrete example than **we don't like pineapple pizza** please?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are not using a [many-to-many](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) as in [this example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/models/#many-to-many-relationships)? 
If that's not the case and you have a ForeignKey in `Topping`, you can do as follows:

```py
pizzas_with_pineapple = Pizza.objects.filter(pk__in=Topping.objects.filter(name='pineapple').values_list('pizza'))

pizzas_without_pineapple = Pizza.objects.exclude(pk__in=Topping.objects.filter(name='pineapple').values_list('pizza'))
```

AFAIK, there is no way to parse pizzas without requesting toppings.